# Using FTP to edit a file removes Apache permissions

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, ftp

If I edit a file using FTP with vsftpd on ubuntu 12.04 LTS... It removes the permissions that allow Apache to access the file...

Currently If I upload a file with FTP, if it is a .php file it will show blank, if it is a .html it will give a page that says "You don't have permission to access /test.html on this server."

However... if I run

```
sudo chmod a+rx ~
sudo chmod -R a+rx ~/public
```

It will fix the problem... and all files in public will be accessible to apache.

But every time I edit it with FTP... it goes back to the white page. and I have to rerun the above commands for it to work.

I can't really wrap my head around how to fix this...

Comment: Where is your Apache folder?

Comment: `/home/public/` I set it to refer to that directory... so `/home/public/index.php` is the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that all i needed to do was edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and uncomment the following line:

```
local_umask=022
```

Then restart the service...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd/ restart
```

This will fix it now.